# How to install Microsoft IPP Class Driver for printer?

Tags: windows-10, network-printer, microsoft

I am deploying a network printer for our office users using CUPS 2.2.7 on an Ubuntu 18.04 server. Tests on my machine (Windows 10 20H2) run fine from my computer when I use the printer driver **Microsoft IPP Class Driver**.

The problem is: I can't find how to deploy this same driver on users machines (1903 to 20H2). It was already installed on my machine (I don't know how or when), but I can't get to install it on other machines.

**Try #1:** Couldn't find any installer for this specific driver. I found an archive containing multiple INF files but when I install them (right click > Install), I get the error "The system cannot find the file specified".

**Try #2:** When digging, I found out that the driver is installed in `C:\Windows\System32\DriverStore\FileRepository\` under `prnms003`. Copy-paste the INF and DLL folders from my machine. The same error as above.

**Try #3:** Export the driver from my machine using `Export-WindowsDriver` from PowerShell. When digging again, I found out that this driver is related to `prnms012` but this latter is not exported by the command.

**Try #4:** Found some sysprep logs deploying `prnmsxxx` but couldn't find which executable or KB is run to get these logs.

**Try #5:** Some users report that when installing some printers (HP ENVY 5540), they got the Microsoft driver configured instead of the manufacturer one. I installed the same manufacturer driver to trigger the same side effect but of course, it didn't do it.

The printer model I have: RICOH MP-2014D. Using the RICOH manufacturer driver on Windows doesn't print anything: a job is created and displayed as completed on the CUPS server, data is also sent to the spool directory, but no actual printing on the printer. Only the Microsoft IPP Class Driver prints successfully.

Thanks guys if you have some inputs on this issue.

Comment: I don't have the means to try this anymore, but I just found out now that adding a new printer device could lead to the Microsoft IPP Class : "Windows Settings > Devices > Printers & scanners > Add", then "The printer that I want is not listed > Add manually", "Add a printer using a TCP/IP address or hostname" → select IPP Device and enter network server IP address, then continue. Again, I cannot test anymore but this could be a hint!

Comment: This worked for me. I suggest adding it as an answer to your own question.

Comment: Done, thanks for the feedback!

Answer (score 2):

The following steps have been proven successful in installing the Microsoft IPP Class Driver:

- Go to `Windows Settings > Devices > Printers & scanners > Add`
- Select `The printer that I want is not listed > Add manually`
- Then `Add a printer using a TCP/IP address or hostname`
- Choose `IPP Device` and enter the IP address/hostname
- Click on `Continue` and go to the end of the procedure.