# What is the current state of the art way to share printers from Linux with Windows clients

Tags: windows, printing, network-printer, print-server, cups

TLDR: What driver should I use in Windows (10/11) to connect to CUPS? Alternatively: What is a better way to print from Windows clients to a Linux server?

Hi,

I'm currently having an Ubuntu 18.04 samba domain member (obviosly to be upgraded) with cups and raw queues as a print server for our windows 10 clients. It works mostly well, even though I have the occasional problem adding a printer driver for older printers. Now we are testing Windows 11 migration and printing seems to be a problem. While testing a newer Ubuntu version with cups, I found a hint in the log, that raw queues are being deprecated. Well I thought, I could try printing directly with IPP, would be nice to get rid of the samba part inbetween client and cups. While my printers are all supported with cups and print quite well from the server, I just cannot get the clients setup correctly.

I tried to add the IPP printer with the *Microsoft IPP Class Driver* I read about in the Internet, but cannot find it. (I only find [questions about the driver missing](https://serverfault.com/questions/1067292/how-to-install-microsoft-ipp-class-driver-for-printer), but never solutions...) What other driver should I use? If I use the driver that matches the printer, it doesn't work (which makes sense, since cups tries to translates it into the printers language as well.)

Or am I on the wrong path here? I just want the users to be able to print from their windows clients on our network printers and have it centrally managed. (Preferably via GPOs) Should I approach this differently?

Clients: Windows 11 22H2, Windows 10 22H2

Answer (score 3):

> What is a better way to print from Windows clients to a Linux server?

Modern CUPS versions support sharing as driverless AirPrint/Mopria printer. This is enabled by default.
Windows 10 1809 and newer support Mopria.

Just share the printer in CUPS (enable `Share printers connected to this system` in the administrator tab of CUPS, and `Share this printer` in the printer settings), then in Windows 10:

1. Open Settings → Printers and scanners → Add a printer or scanner
2. Select the found printer → add device

You don't need to install printer-specific driver on Windows for this.

Another way (a bit more modern) of achieving the same is PAPPL "printer app": https://openprinting.github.io/wsl-printer-app/

Comment: Thanks, I'll try this after my vacation. CUPS is in a different subnet though, so automatic discovery won't work...

Comment: I cannot really find out how this Mopria stuff works. Is it above IPP or does it replace IPP? How can I recognize if the printer is set up via Mopria or via IPP?
I found out that I can add my printers via IPP and the missing driver was due to using the wrong windows dialog. But with IPP some printers dont have settings for enabling/disabling duplex, even though the printers are setup as duplex in CUPS

Comment: @JakobLenfers, Mopria is based on IPP. Mopria provides automatic printer discovery and printing options, but the communications are based on IPP.